# Do I need to install pandoc for html output

Tags: r, r-markdown, pandoc

I am working on an RMarkdown document and I want output results to be displayed in the HTML format using [`rmarkdown`](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=rmarkdown) package. To do so, I need to use the `rmarkdown::render()` function. Is there any way to get the output in HTML without installing pandoc on my PC? Moreover, is it necessary to install pandoc in my PC?

If there is way to get output in html format without having pandoc installed on a PC please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is there any way to get output in html without installing pandoc in my PC.

No, as there is no conversion tool that would then be available.

> Is it necessary to install pandoc in my PC ? If there is way to get output in html format without having pandoc in PC please suggest.

There are two options.

1. Install pandoc stand alone binary
2. Install RStudio, which ships with an embedded version of pandoc.

Both of these strategies would work for rmarkdown.

Comment: Thanks @Coatless for your suggestion.